# Threre is a fast way to communicate between Java and Python with web except for socket?

Tags: java, python, web

I tried using socket. It worked great, and was fast, but I could not read the data from the python server using java. So I want to know if there is a fast way available in both python and java.

**Is there a fast way to transfer data over the internet between Java program and Python??**

Comment: Yes. It is called a "Socket". Why do you think sockets would not work for that?

Comment: Note the title.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with sockets, so why are you looking for something else? You said *"I could not read the data"*, which just means that *you* did something wrong, so if you want help with that, you need to show us what you tried, and explain how it's not working for you.

Comment: You must have access regardless of the programming language. Maybe there is a network or firewall problem. Also, you can look at gRPC for fast and reliable communications.

Comment: To transfer data via a socket (or any other interface, for that matter) you need to specify a format for the transmitted data, and implement the serialization/deserialization to/from that format on both sides. The format can be binary (protobuffers etc) or text based (json, xml,...).

Comment: @ZivSion I read the title. That does not change the situation. You want to transfer data over the Internet. This means IP which in turn means Socket. Period.

Comment: TCP, UDP, and Unix Sockets all works with both Python and Java.

Comment: There is also [py4j](https://www.py4j.org/getting_started.html) and other interoperability projects, but you'll need to tell us a bit more about what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Jython

Run Python code on the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) using [Jython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jython). Have access to Python from Java code, and access to Java from Python code.

See [Jython.org](https://www.jython.org).

Comment: How does that help with "transfer data over the internet"?

Comment: Is it fast like socket?

Comment: Is it going to work on android?

Comment: @ZivSion You should have included Android as a requirement in your Question.